How to connect telegram with session and json file (pyrogram)?
I have .session ang .json file for telegram account, but when I starts script, it gives sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: number err
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
import json
from datetime import datetime
import os

with open('session.json', 'r') as sessiondatafile:
    session_data = json.load(sessiondatafile)


async def main():
    async with Client(name=session_data['session_file'], api_id=session_data["app_id"], api_hash=session_data["app_hash"], app_version=session_data["app_version"], device_model=session_data["device"], system_version=session_data['app_version'], lang_code=session_data['lang_code'], phone_number=session_data['phone']) as app:
        await app.send_video_note(id, video_note=message['circle_id'])
        await app.send_message(id, text=message['text'])

im expecting to authorise tg account and send some message.

The .session file is likely outdated or incompatible with your script's version of Pyrogram or Telegram. To fix this, try deleting the .session file, and run the script again to create a new session file (which should be compatible). Also, make sure all the fields in the .json file are correctly filled.
